# How to get numbers into Lakhs with 4 digit decimal roundoff fraction in excel?

Tags: excel, format, ms-office, excel-2013

I like to convert general number into Lakhs along with 4 digit fractional value roundoff in my excel 2013 as below ,

**Original Number:** `1234567`

**Formatted Number:** `12.3457` (This no is converted multiples of  Lakhs and roundoff with 4 fraction digits).

As a workaround, using `#\.00000` the custom formula in excel (right click number cell -> Format Cells -> under Number tab click "custom" -> In "Type" enter the formula) I made it to display as `12.34567`. But I couldn't roundoff this into 4 fractions digits. How to make it?

Answer (score 1):

How bout using ROUND function?

Let's assume the number is in cell A1.

On cell B1 type

```
=ROUND(A1/100000,4)
```

Comment: yes, I have tried it returns 123.4567 Which is wrong.!

Comment: Is the value for display purpose only? meaning can you use formula for the output? or do you have to have format set and change the number everytime?

Comment: I will be using it for some formula, you can say I have 10 column with data. In 11th column I might be having total column. All the column needs to be formatted in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

try `=ROUND(A1/100000,4)`
. . . . . . . . . .

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have to do it for all the columns in the excel. I can't create formulas an alternative cell and manipulate with original content.